# Splitting a table column into multiple columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

my table looks as follows ( i populate it from a spreadsheet); for a easy manipulation i need to seperate function Code AA column into multiple columns.Values in that column are joined with ,. Separate them with comma seperated values.

```
Eg:
Function CodeAA1    Function CodeAA2  ..
03                    04             ..
```

How can i do that in mysql?

Mysql workbench version 6.3
no limiton those comma seperated column. I expect it goes 1 to 10.
[image]

Comment: Have you used GROUP BY for AA column ?

Comment: @RohanKumar I dint get? How?I think my question is not clear. I edited it with example

Comment: You should also include the expected output, but most likely you can't easily handle your requirement in MySQL, not without using something like a stored procedure.  You should process your CSV _before_ bringing it into your MySQL tables.

Comment: @Ratha - is there a limit of numbers in your `Function Code AA` column ? also please tag your mysql version

Comment: @SudiptaMondal  workbench version is 6.3 and the limit goes 1-10. I have asked another related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908549/can-we-do-a-sql-join-with-or-key-word . I try to get some data from another table based on this comma seperated columns. Is there way to use OR there?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have asked another related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908549/can-we-do-a-sql-join-with-or-key-word

Comment: @Ratha mysql version matters, not the mysql-workbench version.

Answer (score 0):

Some combination of 'word' count, `CASE` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` should get your expected result. Something like below:

```
SELECT fcaa,
       CASE WHEN t_cnt >= 1 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(fcaa, "," ,1) END AS Fcaa1,
       CASE WHEN t_cnt >= 2 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fcaa, "," ,2), "," ,-1) END AS Fcaa2,
       CASE WHEN t_cnt >= 3 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fcaa, "," ,3), "," ,-1) END AS Fcaa3,
       CASE WHEN t_cnt >= 4 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fcaa, "," ,4), "," ,-1) END AS Fcaa4,
       CASE WHEN t_cnt >= 5 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fcaa, "," ,5), "," ,-1) END AS Fcaa5,
       CASE WHEN t_cnt >= 6 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fcaa, "," ,6), "," ,-1) END AS Fcaa6,
       CASE WHEN t_cnt >= 7 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fcaa, "," ,7), "," ,-1) END AS Fcaa7,
       CASE WHEN t_cnt >= 8 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fcaa, "," ,8), "," ,-1) END AS Fcaa8,
       CASE WHEN t_cnt >= 9 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fcaa, "," ,9), "," ,-1) END AS Fcaa9,
       CASE WHEN t_cnt >= 10 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fcaa, "," ,10), "," ,-1) END AS Fcaa10
FROM
(SELECT `yourColumn` AS fcaa,
        (LENGTH(`yourColumn`)-LENGTH(REPLACE(`yourColumn`, "," ,'')))+1 AS t_cnt 
 FROM   yourTable) A;
```

1. The first part is to count how many 'word' in the column row. Hence the usage of whole `LENGTH()` of the data subtract with `LENGTH()` without spaces. We add 1 at the end because if you see one of the example `'03,04,07,08,12,13'` it has 6 occurrence ('word') but if we do  `(LENGTH(yourColumn)-LENGTH(REPLACE(yourColumn,',','')))` without `+1`, we will get 5 count only.
2. The second part is using `CASE` with `SUBSTRING_INDEX`. So when count('t_cnt' - is the word count) matches certain value, then we use corresponding `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function to return the value.

I'm sure there are better ways of doing this but I happen to be doing the same thing before and this method seems like a long one but it works for me. Hopefully, it'll work for you too.