# Can we do a sql join with OR key word?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

My table looks like as follows; (I populated it from excel)
[image]

I want to extract some data from another table so I use sql joins. Since my column contains comma separated values, i try to use join with Or but no success. Is this right way to do joins?
I look for quick solution for this comma separated columns.

eg:

```
SELECT * FROM test.types as a
inner join test.`matric as ma on (a.category= SUBSTRING_INDEX(ma.`Function Code AA`,',',1) 
or a.category= SUBSTRING_INDEX(ma.`Function Code AA`,',',2) 
or a.category= SUBSTRING_INDEX(ma.`Function Code AA`,',',3) 
or a.category= SUBSTRING_INDEX(ma.`Function Code AA`,',',4)
or a.category= SUBSTRING_INDEX(ma.`Function Code AA`,',',5) 
or a.category= SUBSTRING_INDEX(ma.`Function Code AA`,',',6))
and a.type = ma.`function Code NN` and ma.`Priority` = "T1"
```

Comment: You should seriously move away from this table design.  Even `FIND_IN_SET` won't necessarily work here, as `3` does not equal `03`, when both are compared as text.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is not table design. I import a excel file there . Excel file I get from client.So i want to extract data from existing table that is why trying join with excel populated table

Comment: Can you give an answer with Find_ In set? I fix 03/3 issue

Comment: Yes, the `OR` keyword can be used in MySQL inner joins. In your code, you are missing a backtick after `matric` in ```inner join test.`matric ```

Answer (score 0):

You have a horrible data model.  You probably cannot speed up the query very much.  But you can at least simplify the code.

```
SELECT *
FROM test.types t JOIN
     test.matric ma
     ON FIND_IN_SET(t.category, REPLACE(ma.`Function Code AA`, ', ', ',')) > 0 OR
        t.type = ma.`function Code NN` 
WHERE ma.`Priority` = 'T1';
```

However, you should **fix your data model!!!**.  Here are some issues:

- Databases have very poor string processing capabilities.
- Values should be stored using the correct type.
- Foreign keys should be declared properly.
- Such a structure prevents the database from using indexes, partitions, and the best optimization methods.

SQL has a *great* way to store lists.  It is not called a *string*.  It is called a *table*.